# Rails not finding one of my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to customize the after sign up path in my Devise registrations. Per the [instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29) I created a new controller called `therapists_registrations_controller.rb`, but when I start the server and load a page I get `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant TherapistsRegistrationsController)`.

Now `therapists_registrations_controller.rb` is in `app/controllers/api/therapists_registrations_controller.rb`, all the other controllers load and I'm not playing any games with `autoload_paths` or anything. What could be the problem?

This is on Rails 3.2.11. Code for the controller is:

```
class TherapistsRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "http://google.com"
  end  
end
```

Comment: can you please post your routes file, did you use `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "therapists_registrations" }`

Comment: Here's the relevant part: `devise_for :therapists, :controllers => { :registrations => "therapists_registrations" }`.

Comment: What is the path for `therapists_registrations_controller.rb`? `app/api` or `app/controllers/api`?

Comment: It's `app/controllers/api/therapists_registrations_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reason could be the ***class name***. As you have `therapists_registrations_controller.rb` inside the ***app/controllers/api***, the ***class name*** should be

```
class Api::TherapistsRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

***Update:***

You should also change this

```
devise_for :therapists, :controllers => { :registrations => "therapists_registrations" }
```

to

```
devise_for :therapists, :controllers => { :registrations => "api/therapists_registrations" }
```

Comment: @Johnny Ok. Also try changing this `devise_for :therapists, :controllers => { :registrations => "therapists_registrations" }` to `devise_for :therapists, :controllers => { :registrations => "api/therapists_registrations" }`